# Copy same file to different directories

Tags: copy, cmd, rename, copy-paste, pascalscript

Is there a program (or a code for ReNamer or .cmd) that will copy the file readme.txt to every directory in the same directory as readme.txt is?

ReNamer: http://www.den4b.com/?x=products&product=renamer (there is a PascalScript rule, which let users program their very own renaming rule.)

I daily get over 50 new directories from work, they all need this file inside it. I've done over 1000 manually, I hope there is a solution for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a Batch script:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "startdir=X:\start\folder"
for /d /r "%startdir%" %%i in (*.*) do copy readme.txt "%%~i"
endlocal
```

Comment: I made a copy.bat with your provided content, but it didnt work:`code` @echo off &setlocal
set "startdir=C:\Work_VideoClasses"
for /d /r "%startdir%" %%i in (*.*) do copy readme.txt "%%~i"
endlocal`code`

Comment: check the output from this test code: `@echo off &setlocal`
`set "startdir=C:\Work_VideoClasses"`
`for /d /r "%startdir%" %%i in (*.*) do echo copy readme.txt "%%~i"`
`endlocal`

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
FOR /R %%f in (.) DO xcopy readme.txt %%f
```

You save the .bat file in the same location as readme.txt, AND the subdirectries must be in the same folder as readme.txt:
i.e

```
Desktop
    readme.txt 
    name.bat
    Sub1
    Sub2
    Sub3
```

etc....

Comment: I made a copy.bat with your provided content, and did exactly what you said, but it didnt work:`code` @echo off
FOR /R %%f in (.) DO xcopy readme.txt %%f`code`

Answer (score 0):

Below is a PascalScript code for [ReNamer](http://www.den4b.com/?x=products&product=renamer) which will create a *Readme.txt* file in every processed folder.

The script is executed during the preview, so for safety it will ask you whether to create *Readme.txt* or not every time you preview. This script uses `ReadmeText` constant for the content, but it could also be made that it copies the content of *Readme.txt* file from a file on your system. It will only create a *Readme.txt* file if one does not already exist. Drop all your folders into ReNamer and use this script.

```
const
  ReadmeName = 'Readme.txt';
  ReadmeText = 'Content of Readme file goes here!';
var
  Initialized: Boolean;
  ReadmePath: WideString;
  DoCreateReadmeFile: Boolean;
begin
  if not Initialized then
  begin
    Initialized := True;
    DoCreateReadmeFile := DialogYesNo('Create Readme file this time?');
  end;
  if WideDirectoryExists(FilePath) then
    ReadmePath := WideIncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(FilePath)
  else
    ReadmePath := WideExtractFilePath(FilePath);
  ReadmePath := ReadmePath + ReadmeName;
  if DoCreateReadmeFile and not WideFileExists(ReadmePath) then
    FileWriteContent(ReadmePath, ReadmeText);
end.
```

### Edit

Script below will take a source file defined by `SourceFilePath` and copy it to the target folders. It will also warn you if source file does not exist.

```
const
  TargetFileName = 'Readme.txt';
  SourceFilePath = 'C:\Temp\Readme.txt';
var
  Initialized: Boolean;
  TargetFilePath: WideString;
  DoCreateFiles: Boolean;
begin
  if not Initialized then
  begin
    Initialized := True;
    if WideFileExists(SourceFilePath) then
      DoCreateFiles := WideDialogYesNo('Create "'+TargetFileName+'" files this time?')
    else
      WideShowMessage('Source file does not exist!'+#13#13+SourceFilePath);
  end;
  if WideDirectoryExists(FilePath) then
    TargetFilePath := WideIncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(FilePath)
  else
    TargetFilePath := WideExtractFilePath(FilePath);
  TargetFilePath := TargetFilePath + TargetFileName;
  if DoCreateFiles and not WideFileExists(TargetFilePath) then
    WideCopyFile(SourceFilePath, TargetFilePath, False);
end.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but what about other files? f.e. an JPG - it would be really cool if you can give a path to a file, and copy this file to every dir you load up in ReNamer.

Comment: @WHOMEZz I have edited the post and added a script which will take a source file defined by `SourceFilePath` and copy it to the target folders.